# Is $w^{-1} e_{\alpha} w = e_{w^{-1}(\alpha)}$?

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras

Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be a semisimple Lie algebra and $e_{\alpha}$ a root vector, $\alpha$ is a positive root. Let $w \in W$, where $W$ is the Weyl group of $\mathfrak{g}$. Is $w^{-1} e_{\alpha} w = e_{w^{-1}(\alpha)}$? Thank you very much.

Comment: Usually the Weyl group acts on the Cartan subalgebra of $\mathfrak g$ and on its dual, but not on $\mathfrak g$ itself. Maybe you are confusing this with the fact that $w^{-1}s_{\alpha}w=s_{w^{-1}(\alpha)}$, were $s$ denotes the root reflection.